# How to parse a txt web service

Tags: java, web-services

I'm trying to obtain a result from a web service in a java program. I've done xml services before but this one is text based and i can't figure out how to record the response.

Here is the webService: http://ws.geonames.org/countryCode?lat=47.03&lng=10.2

Thanks!

Comment: what implementation are you using for REST services? Jersey?

Comment: What are typical results and what do you want to get?

Comment: It will return a two letter country code, thats what i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's only text, and you doesn't use any standard format (like SOAP), you need to use Sockets:

```
URL myURL = new URL("http://ws.geonames.org/countryCode?lat=47.03&lng=10.2");
URLConnection serviceConnection = myURL.openConnection();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                               serviceConnection.getInputStream()));

List<String> response =new ArrayList<String>();
```

Use this if you had many lines:

```
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
   response.add(inputLine);
```

Or use this if you had ONLY ONE line (like the Web Service in your question):

```
String countryCode = in.readLine();
```

And finish with:

```
serviceConnection.close();
```

In my case, countryCode it was "AT"

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CountryCodeReader {

    private String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int cp;
        while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
            sb.append((char) cp);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public String readFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
        InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
        try {
            InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(is);

            return readAll(rd);
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        CountryCodeReader ccr = new CountryCodeReader(); 
        String cc = ccr.readFromUrl("http://ws.geonames.org/countryCode?lat=47.03&lng=10.2");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative implementation in addition to URL is to use a HttpClient.